# New bathroom fan has 2 green wires but i do not know where to connect them

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan

A new bathroom fan I want to install has 2 green and 1 each white and black. The line in the attic consists of a white, a black and a ground. What do I do with the 2 green wires?

Comment: All green wires are grounds.  Ground is bare, yellow/green or green.  That's the one wire standard the whole world agreed on!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: I used a system that used green for Common. The system had no ground per say, but Common was the thing everything connected to. The whole thing floated with respect to building ground due to transformer decoupling.

Answer (score 3):

Green designates a ground (earth) wire. If the incoming wires have a ground wire (usually bare copper or green stranded insulated) attach the grounds to it with a wire nut or a crimp connector.

Answer (score 2):

In Alternating current (AC) electrical distribution,   that is used in providing electricity to light fixtures, switches and outlets in buildings,  the ground wires are bare copper. Since it does not carry and load, *electricity*, it has no need for an insulating cover. When the ground wire enters a fixture box or outlet box it is tied together with other ground wires that are/may be entering the box.

All of the ground wires in the system are connected back at the main breaker box which is connected to  the earth (*grounded*) via a grounding rod. This creates a ground through out the whole system.

If the fixture box is metal then the bare ground wires are usually attached to the box thereby grounding the box to the system, or if the box is plastic they are  tied together with a crimp or a wire nut or just twisted very tightly together with linesman pliers.

> What do i do with 2 green wires

In fixtures and devices   Green insulation is used  on wires as the designated color to indicate that it is a ground wire.
When installing a light fixture you need to connect the Green wire(s) of the fixture to the ground wires in the box. This can be done with a wire nut or, if it is a metal box that is grounded, with a screw to the  body of the box.

All fixtures, switches and outlet receptacles are required to be grounded. (*connected to the ground system*)

Answer (score -4):

Don't love any of the answers given so I will simplify.

If there was no circuits in the house, you could wire your whole house with one live and one ground cable.

As it happens, houses are "filled to the brim" with circuits.

Every circuit breaker, every electrical box etc is a circuit.

Because you need continuity from circuit to circuit that's why all houses have two live wire: black and white.  BTW, the your electrical box is both the beginning and end of all the circuits in your house.  The very presence of black and white cables in any "to be wired" home product means "this product was engineered to be part of a circuit".  Once you connect the bathroom fan, black to black and white to white, you have completed an additional circuit.

Certain conditions can cause live wires to melt or arc (Large spark).  Wouldn't it be great if we could control where that happens.  So the electrical box has a ground for each switch, but its possible that lightning could sever that ground, more electricity than the ground wire could handle, so let's not just rely on the electrical panel ground, but let's integrate a ground into the "home wired products" as well.  And electrons take the path of least resistance meaning if the electrical box ground (wall wire) is tied with the other two green or bare from the "wired home product", most of the brute is taken by the bathroom fan steel box; steel contains arcs hence electrical boxes and an added bonus that your circuit ground probably will survive.

In short, wire all grounds together.  As you know the bathroom fan is usually part of a light circuit, so the bathroom fan could be somewhere in the middle of a bunch of a light circuit.  So it stands to reason if you don't want want zero notification of problems with a bathroom fan circuit
you would simply connect both green wires part of the bathroom fan.  That way the electrical box switch for that light circuit will only be triggered by light circuit incidences; assuming only lights and the bathroom fan is on that circuit.  However, I advise against this.  You want notification of every electrical incidence.  So as I have said, in short wire all grounds together, but make sure the "wired home product" ground is secured tightly with screw into steel box; verify it's nice and snug.

Comment: Seems like some confusion in concepts between earth ground and neutral return. Also on definition of "circuit" and "live".

Comment: Seems like much confusion in concepts!